# Windows: How do folder permissions affect file permissions inside

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm on Ubuntu here and have no Windows available, so please forgive me if this is obvious. My last Windows machine was XP, so my knowledge is kind of outdated.

Say I have a folder with three files in it:

```
my-folder
 | .
 | ..
 | some-file-a.txt
 | some-file-b.txt
 | some-file-c.txt
```

And the following permissions:

- `my-folder`: R/W for admins only
- `some-file-a.txt`: R/W for all
- `some-file-b.txt`: R/W for `user-a`, and `user-a` only
- `some-file-c.txt`: R/W for admins only

So file c is pretty clear: file and folder allow admins only.

But what about file b: Do admins have access?  Does `user-a` has access, given the fact, that the containing folder doesn't allow access except for admins?

And who can access file a?